# Python script to filter nested data from json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** data from a nested JSON file, my goal is to extract `"QUANTITE"` value in a specific nest.
The JSON file have a repeated pattern :

```
    "T_INDICATEUR_QUANTITEs": [
        {
            "T_INDICATEUR_NORMEs": null,
            "T_PHASE_NORMEs": null,
            "ID_INDICATEUR_QUANTITE": 706222,
            "ID_PRODUIT": 5881,
            "QUANTITE": 18.8,
            "ID_INDICATEUR_NORME": 32,
            "ID_PHASE_NORME": 23
        },
        {
            "T_INDICATEUR_NORMEs": null,
            "T_PHASE_NORMEs": null,
            "ID_INDICATEUR_QUANTITE": 706223,
            "ID_PRODUIT": 5881,
            "QUANTITE": 20.6,
            "ID_INDICATEUR_NORME": 32,
            "ID_PHASE_NORME": 39
        },
        {
            "T_INDICATEUR_NORMEs": null,
            "T_PHASE_NORMEs": null,
            "ID_INDICATEUR_QUANTITE": 706224,
            "ID_PRODUIT": 5881,
            "QUANTITE": 0.191,
            "ID_INDICATEUR_NORME": 32,
            "ID_PHASE_NORME": 24
        },
```

Each `"QUANTITE"` value has a specific couple `"ID_INDICATEUR_NORME"`,`"ID_PHASE_NORME"`

How can I have the value of `"QUANTITE"` for a specific couple `"ID_INDICATEUR_NORME"`,`"ID_PHASE_NORME"`?

Thanks in advance!

[Link of the complete file](https://pastebin.com/AL2nVjqE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the simplest way to do this,

```py
import json

# Loding the data
with open('#File path or website URL here','r') as file:
    content = file.read()

# Converting json_data to python dictionary format
json_data = json.loads(content)

quantite = -1 # -1 for not found case
for data in json_data['T_INDICATEUR_QUANTITEs']:
    
    # Checking for specific pair
    if data['ID_INDICATEUR_NORME'] == x and data['ID_PHASE_NORME'] == y:
        quantite = data['QUANTITE'] 
        break

print(f"QUANTITE value is {quantite}")
```

here `x` and `y` are the specific values for your `ID_INDICATEUR_NORME` and `ID_PHASE_NORME`.

This snippet will return `QUANTITE` value if your **specific pair** is matched else it will return `-1`

Answer (score 0):

First import json
and then dict = json.loads(data)  to parse "QUANTITE"
all code like this:

```
import json

data = '{"T_INDICATEUR_QUANTITEs": [ \
        { \
            "T_INDICATEUR_NORMEs": null,\
            "T_PHASE_NORMEs": null, \
            "ID_INDICATEUR_QUANTITE": 706222,\
            "ID_PRODUIT": 5881,\
            "QUANTITE": 18.8,\
            "ID_INDICATEUR_NORME": 32,\
            "ID_PHASE_NORME": 23\
        },\
        {\
            "T_INDICATEUR_NORMEs": null,\
            "T_PHASE_NORMEs": null,\
            "ID_INDICATEUR_QUANTITE": 706223,\
            "ID_PRODUIT": 5881,\
            "QUANTITE": 20.6,\
            "ID_INDICATEUR_NORME": 32,\
            "ID_PHASE_NORME": 39\
        },\
        {\
            "T_INDICATEUR_NORMEs": null,\
            "T_PHASE_NORMEs": null,\
            "ID_INDICATEUR_QUANTITE": 706224,\
            "ID_PRODUIT": 5881,\
            "QUANTITE": 0.191,\
            "ID_INDICATEUR_NORME": 32,\
            "ID_PHASE_NORME": 24\
        }\
    ]\
}'

dict = json.loads(data)

dataList = dict["T_INDICATEUR_QUANTITEs"]

for data in dataList:
    print(data["QUANTITE"])
```

Result:

```
18.8
20.6
0.191
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easy.

```py
with open("a.json") as jsonfile: # load process
   data = jsonfile.read() # read it up
load = json.load(data) # and extract to each dict

# using
load["Data that you want"]
```